# Accessing polymorphic pivot tables attributes in laravel 6

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-6

I am trying to use polymorphic many to many relationships. I have images that can be linked to several different types of model. Each model could have more than one image but can only have one default image (thumbnail). I thought I could achieve this by adding a column to the pivot table like this:

```
Schema::create('image_links', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('image_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('image_links_id');
        $table->string('image_links_type');
        $table->boolean('default_image');
    });
```

I have defined the relationships as follows:

Image:

```
public function model1()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Model1', 'image_links')->withPivot('default_image');
}
```

Modal1:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Image', 'image_links')->withPivot('default_image');
}
```

In the Model1 controller I am looking through etch Madel1 like this:

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

    foreach ($user->modal1as $model1) {

        $images = Image::find($model1->id);

        if (!empty($images)) {
            $model1->image = Image::find($model1->id);

            dd($model1);
        }
```

From the research I have done I'm expecting access the default_image column like this:

```
$model1->default_image
```

But when I dd it, it comes up with NULL. I need to be able to search the database and only retrieve the image with default_image set as 1.

I thought that this was possible but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried it like this:

```
$image = Image::find($model1->id)->where('default_image = 1');
            // $images = Image::get();

            dd($image);
```

This returns:

```
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#302 ▼
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#298 ▶}
  #model: App\Image {#317 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:17 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

I can not see how to access the image details.

Edit:

Here are some other things I have now tried.

I'm in the model1 controller and I want to retrieve the images linked to model1 that have the default_image value of 1. I don't think I am querying the database correctly in the first instance. I have realised that

`$images = Image::find($model1->id);`

retrieves the image with the same id at the current model1 id witch is incorrect. I have tried

`$images = App\Image::whereHasMorph(
                'image_links',
                ['App\Model1'],
                function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('id', 'like', $GLOBALS['id']);
                }
            )->get();`

That returned Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Image' not found I look out the App\ and added use App\Image and got Call to undefined method App\Image::image_links(). I am now really lost with this ant in need of help.

14/04/2020 Update.

I have now changed `image_links` to `imageables`. However, this still has not worked. I tried to access the images like this:

```
use App\Model1

$modal1 = Model1::get();
return $model1->images;
```

This gives me this error: Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.

Please can someone help with this?

Other info:
I am running WAMP on Windows 10

Comment: You should create another table `imageables` where you would have polymorphic relationship, something like this
`imageables` with columns:
    `image_id` - integer
   `imageable_id` - integer
   `imageable_type` - string

For more information check the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Hi, @StefanTanevski Thank you for you help. I do have the `image_links` table that has the received columns plus my custom one `default_image`. Can this table not have a custom name or does it need to follow the `ables` convention?

Comment: If you are not following the laravel convention, you would have to explicitely pass the names of the columns

Comment: Hi, I have now renamed everything to imageable but it is still not working.

Comment: Please see my update